# Want to set my dual boot because it got desipeared

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount, windows

I tried to know were linux is installed I didn't find the path using `sudo fdisk -l` to work on grub fix problem so this is what I got after this command :

```
sudo fdisk -l

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     923648   1126399    202752    99M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1126400   1159167     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1159168 215541759 214382592 102.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  215541760 478918374 263376615 125.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  623337472 625139711   1802240   880M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  478918656 621336575 142417920  67.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8  621336576 623337471   2000896   977M Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: If you run " sudo update-grub" it automatically searches through the entire disk and finds your OSes and adds them to the grub menu . You don't have to worry about the partition names or labels.

Comment: Did you install in UEFI boot mode? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

This might work:
Create an Ubuntu live usb.
Choose it in BIOS. You will have multiple options. Select Boot Repair.
This should reinstall grub.
WARNING! I am not sure if it deletes user data or not. I am not responsible if you lose your data.